# Time Picker dialog will not show

Tags: android, timepicker

I am new, i apologize, i had searched but could not find an answer in previous questions.
I have a date picker and a time picker yet when i run it, the time picker dialog does not show. Any idea?  I searched for an answer for hours, this is the code i have:

```
    public class BuildingFireActivity extends Activity {

private Button buildingfirePickDate;
private Button buildingfiredispatchPickTime;

private TextView buildingfireDateDisplay;
private TextView buildingfiredispatchTimeDisplay;

private int buildingfireYear;
private int buildingfireMonth;
private int buildingfireDay;
private int buildingfiredispatchHour;
private int buildingfiredispatchMinute;

static final int DATE_DIALOG_ID = 0;
static final int TIME_DIALOG_ID = 1;


public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.buildingfirelayout);

    buildingfirePickDate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pickDate);
    buildingfiredispatchPickTime = (Button) findViewById(R.id.dispatchTime);

    buildingfireDateDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dateDisplay);
    buildingfiredispatchTimeDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dispatchDisplay);

    buildingfirePickDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public void onClick(View v) {
    showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);}});
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    buildingfireYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    buildingfireMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    buildingfireDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    updateDisplay();
    buildingfiredispatchPickTime.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public void onClick(View v) {
    showDialog(TIME_DIALOG_ID);}});
    final Calendar dispatch = Calendar.getInstance();
    buildingfiredispatchHour = dispatch.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    buildingfiredispatchMinute = dispatch.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    updateDisplay1();}
private static String pad(int dispatch) {
    if (dispatch >= 10)
    return String.valueOf(dispatch);
    else
    return "0" + String.valueOf(dispatch);}


private void updateDisplay() {
    buildingfireDateDisplay.setText(
    new StringBuilder()
    .append(buildingfireMonth + 1).append("-")
    .append(buildingfireDay).append("-")
    .append(buildingfireYear).append(" "));}
private void updateDisplay1() {
    buildingfiredispatchTimeDisplay.setText(
    new StringBuilder()
    .append(pad(buildingfiredispatchHour)).append(":")
    .append(pad(buildingfiredispatchMinute)));}

private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener buildingfireDateSetListener =
    new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
            buildingfireYear = year;
            buildingfireMonth = monthOfYear;
            buildingfireDay = dayOfMonth;
            updateDisplay();}};
private TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener buildingfiredispatchTimeSetListener =
    new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
            buildingfiredispatchHour = hourOfDay;
            buildingfiredispatchMinute = minute;
            updateDisplay1();}}; 



protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
    case TIME_DIALOG_ID:
    return new TimePickerDialog(this,
            buildingfiredispatchTimeSetListener, 
            buildingfiredispatchHour, 
            buildingfiredispatchMinute, false);}
            return null;}

@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog1(int id) {
    switch (id) {
    case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
    return new DatePickerDialog(this,
            buildingfireDateSetListener,
            buildingfireYear, 
            buildingfireMonth, 
            buildingfireDay);}
            return null;}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
    case TIME_DIALOG_ID:
    return new TimePickerDialog(this,
        buildingfiredispatchTimeSetListener, 
        buildingfiredispatchHour, 
        buildingfiredispatchMinute, false);
    case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
    return new DatePickerDialog(this,
        buildingfireDateSetListener,
        buildingfireYear, 
        buildingfireMonth, 
        buildingfireDay);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Try to use this code and remove the `onCreateDialog1()`.

Comment: Thank you, very helpful!  Do you have any other suggestions to clean up or reduce amount of code on this?

Comment: I also tried to solve your problem. In my case the datepicker dialog throws an error and the timepicker dialog shows, however you have unnecessary suppresswarnings. Remove them.

Comment: Try to write formated code. At least use eclipse formatter to format your code. Then other people can easily understand you code. If you want to learn try to write your own code. By copying you'll only get your result, not the learning part.

Comment: Thank you, also helpful, i was not aware of the format feature.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Can u try this code i hope it helps to see Date picker dialog box

Select date from dialog and display it in TextView.

```
public class DatePickerDemoActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

   private TextView mDateDisplay;
    private Button mPickDate;
    private int mYear;
    private int mMonth;
    private int mDay;

    static final int DATE_DIALOG_ID = 0;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // capture our View elements
    mDateDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dateDisplay);
    mPickDate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pickDate);

    // add a click listener to the button
    mPickDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);
        }
    });

    // get the current date
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    // display the current date (this method is below)
    updateDisplay();
}

// updates the date in the TextView
private void updateDisplay() {
    mDateDisplay.setText(getString(R.string.strSelectedDate,
        new StringBuilder()
                // Month is 0 based so add 1
                .append(mMonth + 1).append("-")
                .append(mDay).append("-")
                .append(mYear).append(" ")));
}

// the callback received when the user "sets" the date in the dialog
private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mDateSetListener =
        new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,
                                  int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                mYear = year;
                mMonth = monthOfYear;
                mDay = dayOfMonth;
                updateDisplay();
            }
        };

@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
    case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
        return new DatePickerDialog(this, mDateSetListener, mYear, mMonth,
                mDay);
    }
    return null;
}
}
```